# Subdomain Zend Framework

Tags: apache, zend-framework, localhost, virtualhost

I have to modify an existing web application with zend framework.
The application contains differents Modules that are accessible with subdomain.

On my dev environment the application works good if I use localhost in link (Example: SubDomainName.localhost)

I want to connect from another Machine to my application in local network.That why I add virtual host (parisparis.dev) in my Apache webserver , but it did not work even locally
(Example not work SubDomainName.parisparis.dev error 
This site is inaccessible)

**httpd.conf** I activate

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<NameVirtualHost> *
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName parisparis.dev
   ServerAlias *.parisparis.dev
    ServerAdmin webmastessr@localhost
      DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/www/public"
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "production"
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/www/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All 
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Hosts** on my mac "/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
192.168.1.3 parisparis.dev www.parisparis.dev
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
127.0.0.1 Air-de-mac # added by Apache Friends XAMPP
```

In my **application.ini** I change this :

```
resources.router.routes.travel.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
<b>resources.router.routes.travel.route = ":module.localhost"</b>
resources.router.routes.travel.defaults.module = "hotels"
```

by

```
resources.router.routes.travel.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
<b>resources.router.routes.travel.route = ":module.parisparis.dev"</b>
resources.router.routes.travel.defaults.module = "hotels"
```